# Quiero imprimir el vector "x" pero no me deja insertar numeros decimales dentro del mismo. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tags: fortran

```
program p4
implicit none
real :: x(6), y(6)

x=[1.6,2,2.5,3.2,4,4.5]
y=[2, 8, 14, 15, 8, 2]
write(*,*) y

pause
end program p4
```

Quiero imprimir el vector "x" pero no me deja insertar numeros decimales dentro del mismo. Al momento de compilar el programa me sale el error: *Error: Element in REAL(4) array constructor at (1) is INTEGER(4)*
¿Qué puedo hacer?

Quiero, al momento de imprimir "x", obtener en el prompt "1.6, 2, 2.5, 3.2, 4, 4.5"

Answer (score 0):

Pareciera que lo siguiente es lo que necesitas para lograr lo que quieres:

1. El arreglo `x` contiene elementos de tipo `integer` y `real` mezclados, habrá que cambiar los elementos `integer` agregándoles `.0` i.e.:

```
x = [1.6, 2.0, 2.5, 3.2, 4.0, 4.5]
```

2. El arreglo que estás imprimiendo es `y`, habrá que cambiarlo por `x`
3. Para tener el output que esperas será necesario utilizar un ciclo donde vayas imprimiendo cada elemento del arreglo. Esto requiere algunos detalles no triviales:

   1. Deberás identificar cuáles elementos tienen parte decimal y cuáles no para utilizar el formato adecuado como segundo parámetro de `write`
   2. Deberás verificar si estás a punto de imprimir el último elemento del arreglo

Como ejemplo llegué al siguiente programa:

```
program p4
    implicit none
    real :: x(6), y(6)
    integer :: i, integerPart, xSize
    real :: decimalPart, num

    x = [1.6,2.0,2.5,3.2,4.0,4.5]
    y = [2, 8, 14, 15, 8, 2]

    xSize = SIZE(x)

    do i = 1, xSize
        num = x(i)
        integerPart = INT(num)
        decimalPart = num - FLOAT(integerPart)
        if (decimalPart /= 0) THEN
            write(*, '(F3.1)', advance='no') num
        else
            write(*, '(I1)', advance='no') integerPart
        end if

        if (i /= xSize) then
            write(*, '(A)', advance='no') ','
        end if
        write(*, '(A)', advance='no') ' '
    end do

end program p4
```

Esto está lejos de ser una manera general de imprimir cualquier arreglo arbitrario de reales con un formato parecido (i.e. concatenar los elementos del arreglo usando la menor cantidad posible de decimales para cada elemento)